# Date tokens for file path

Tags: files

I have a big site with a lot of images and I want to use Date tokens for the File path.
So I edit the image file and set Filepath: [current-date:short]

I have the following issue:
1)Uploaded images are broken
What could be the reason for this?
thanks

Comment: If you are setting the file path as a date format, how can you ever expect it to work?
Images are broken because you are not specifying a file location, or a file extension.

Comment: Hi I saw this in an article from Acquia.However it doesn't work for me.
http://www.slideshare.net/AcquiaInc/preventing-drupal-headaches-establishing-flexible-file-paths-from-the-start

Comment: Anyone else help me on this please?

Comment: just enable pathauto module and tokens will work, i use [current-date:raw]

Answer (score 0):

Configuration > Regional and Language > Date and Time

Check what your default Short time format is. If its being printed with spaces, it could be part of the problem. 
You could add a new date type, and see if that fixes anything.

The easy way around this, is when managing the image and file upload CCK fields, just specify a directory for those images in the field settings there.

Comment: I created a new date format like this Y/m/d added this format to the image field.
Again the images that I upload are broken...

Comment: Are you flushing the cache each time? And when you are entering the token for the short date format, and you putting it in Configuration > Media > File Sytem > "public file system path"? Or in the file directory field for an image or file type?

Comment: I cleared the cache but no luck.Also I don't use the Media module,I only use the Drupal core image field.And I put this current date format in the settings of the Image field on the content type.

Comment: It isnt part of the media module, its at admin/config/media/file-system . Are you sure these fields accept tokens?
Do you have a URL I can look at? Or can you debug the broken image file once you have uploaded it, and seen where the file path is pointing to?

Comment: The admin/config/media/file-system doesn't accept tokens.Only the field image is accepting tokens.After uploading an image,the folders are created and also the   
images are uploaded to the folders,but they appear as broken.
I don't have an live URL so as you to have a look.
Also I am not sure how to debug this.
You can try this on a test site you have following th e same steps.i.e. adding date tokens to an image field.
And thanks for your help.

Comment: I just set it up on one of my sites on a new content type, with an image field, with the file directory as [current-date:short], and it created the folders, and the image displayed perfectly! This may not be the issue after all! using google chrome, right click on the image and click "inspect element". Is the image src as you would expect?

Comment: Hmm,I did what you told me.Here is the image src <img src="http://localhost/cars-test/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/03/11/2014%20-%2023%3A15/screenshot2.png?itok=l9EX3H6_" width="480" height="270" alt="">

This is not what i expected,but I am not sure what is causing this...

Comment: Are you using the adaptive image module? That normally separates the images into different folders for different screen widths, which would explain the /styles/large bit. have you removed the image name from that bit of code? Or is that exactly as you copied it? because there is no file name there.

Comment: I am not using the adaptive image module.I am not using any other image module.Also there is the name of the file there,it is called screenshot2.png